# Get the feature points of a character image for point matching

Tags: android, image-processing, matching

I browsed around the internet and could not find any point matching implementation on java.
Therefore I would like to create my own simple one that apply on simple line matching by following a tutorial

My first step would like to obtain some "points" as below to express the feature of an image.
Is it a good approach to apply a thinning (skeleton) algorithm before getting the points?
But I have no much idea on obtaining meaningful points in this next step, could anyone give me some guidance?

Please also point out if I am actually doing something silly that is unreasonable.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean character recognition?

Comment: Maybe but not exactly. Actually I would like to compare the similarity between different handwritten character with computer font. 

I did tried many other algorithms for image comparison but the result is quite inaccurate. Main reason is that the handwritten characters to be matched are looking quite close, other algorithms may treat them the same thing, then I cannot tell their difference through image comparison. And finally, I try to go for point matching and come to the current question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step should be to define what transformation your matching points should survive through - is it just translation or also rotation, scaling, shear, etc? Your second step is to outline the useful properties for matching  - that is points should stable to noise and transformation, well localized and supplied with a unique descriptor to actually match them with this "Signautre". Opencv has a java library, so you can start with the slowest but well worked out points and descriptors  like SIFT, SURF and work your way up to FAST and your own descriptor, which can be faster but is more work.

Alternatively, you can just find well defined points in your font and use geometric hashing if you sure there are correspondences. In this case you dont need descriptors or even explicit matching. See Wikipedia article on geometric hashing. I think in a simple form it provides methodology for rotation and scaling transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiring information! My "input" is assumed to be similar size with "signature", a bit distorted but not rotated. As mentioned in the above comment, I am looking for sometime which is able to distinguish the similarity (in % maybe) between different handwritten word of same character. Is your suggested geometric hashing a good approach to do this once the feature points are collected?

Comment: Well, if you can extract same characters and then split them on the same number of points than geometric hashing indeed can be useful. What else can be useful is so-called statistical model of shape where you model deviations from the mean shape. You even can perform PCA on these deviations to discover a few hidden dimensions in shape variations, see http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/s.prince/book/17_Models_For_Shape.pptx